# How to add an integer into String using objective c?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I am a java programmer, I found that Java is very good at doing string.

If I want to do this objective c, how can I do in objective c ?

```
System.out.println("This is a " + 123 + " test");
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To place an integer into a string, you can do this:

```
int n = 123;
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a %d test", n];
```

There are numerous other ways. But concatenating strings with integers by + operator is not one of them. :)

Comment: And for printing debugging output to the console, NSLog() is your friend.

Comment: As in, NSLog(CFSTR("This is a %d test"), n); The difference of syntax has to do with the fact that NSString is an Objective C class with methods, and NSLog is a C function.

Comment: @Seva that works, but it's much easier to do: `NSLog(@"This is a %d test", n);`  Even though `NSLog` is a C function, it takes `NSString*,...` as its arguments.

Comment: You know... conceptual purity :) I'm pretending CFString and NSString are distinct, even though they're the same.

Comment: But you can have C functions that take objective C objects that don't have Core Foundation equivalents…

Comment: Well, yeah... so what? NSLog is documented to take a CFStringRef as a parameter. So I gave it one.

Answer (score 0):

To place an integer into a string, you can do this:

```
int number = 123;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a %i test", number];
```

Or if you want to `NSLog` you have to do this :

```
int number = 123;
NSLog(@"This is a %i test", number);
```

It is very EASY !!!